# Move element in div to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element on a mouse over event that I would like to be animate and move to the left. I have what I thought was the correct code in a fidle but it seems just mot to work.

here is the fiddle I created:

https://jsfiddle.net/feb8rdwp/3/

here is the code I used - simple but based on this it really should work: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1

```js
$(".Submit a").mouseover(function(){
        $(".fadeInLeftBig").animate({left: '750px'});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation fadeInLeftBig animated"><img alt="" src="http://younggraphics.com.au/Portals/0/images/skin/car.png" /></div>
<div class="Submit"><a id="dnn_ctr461_FormsView_lnkSubmitEmail" class="Button_default" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("dnn$ctr461$FormsView$lnkSubmitEmail", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Submit</a></div>
```

Comment: You have not included jQuery in JSfiddle. Also there is no CSS applied initially.

Comment: doh your right - added and updated. Still no go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply `left` property, make the element position relative/absolute to the parent,

```
.animation{
    position:relative;
}
```

Or use `marginLeft`

```
$(".Submit a").mouseover(function(){
    $(".fadeInLeftBig").animate({marginLeft: '750px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add jQuery as a library to your fiddle and second if you want to use left then you need to set the element to absolute position, which means parent requires relative position

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;">This div can use the left css</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feb8rdwp/5/

Comment: Wow, that car takes off like a bat out of hell!

Comment: And I feel like a mechanic who just fixed a car

Comment: I wonder these animations might set wrong expectations from Automobile manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try like this:

```
$('.block').mouseover(function() {       
 $(this).animate({"left": "+=700px"},"slow");
});
```

you can try here - https://jsfiddle.net/dimitrioglo/ebkc9dzL/25/

Answer (score 0):

The working example:

```
 <div class="Submit"><a id="dnn_ctr461_FormsView_lnkSubmitEmail" class="Button_default" href='#'>Submit</a></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(ee){    
     $(".Button_default").click(function(){      
        $(".fadeInLeftBig").animate({left: '750px'});
    });  
});
```